# How long does a widget's BuildContext live?

Tags: flutter, dart

As per my understanding, context is unique for every widget and contains information about widget's location in the widget tree. When we pop a navigation route, the widget is removed from the navigation stack and finally disposed. If I try to pop app drawer using a clickable widget (button or gesture detector) and then immediately push a new route, it works fine. But it gives exception (Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.) when I enclosed the push command in a delayed future.

Code :

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop();
 Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('foo_route');
 });
```

Outcome : Exception => Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop();
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('foo_route');
```

Outcome : Works as expected. App drawer is poped and new route pushed.

I know why the exception is raised. But it should have been raised for the second code as well. It seems that the context lives for a very small amount of time.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this in your code, you can also await the Navigator.pop()

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
 Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('foo_route');
 });
            });
```

i hope this helps.